# ADFS - windows auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, adfs2.0

We noticed that Windows Authentication required several round trips for each resource request in our ASP.NET MVC app. We believe that we can reduce this to one round trip per resource by  passing a cookie along with each request. As far as I know the following should be possible:

1) user navigates to http://server/app

2) http://server/app does not find a cookie and redirects to http://authserver/authapp

3) http://authserver/authapp recognises the windows user and a request for claims for http://server/app

4) http://authserver/authapp issues a cookie with claims and redirects to http://server/app

Is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the WS-Federation passive mechanism supported by some STS endpoints. Are you asking if this will work with ADFS2.0? Because yes this is the simplest use-case.